# How to sort html files to display they to older to newest at page?

Tags: php, html, file, sorting, scandir

To show all files from folder i use this.

```
<?php
    foreach (glob("pardod/*.html") as $filename)
    {
        include $filename;
    }
?>
```

Yes, its show that what i want but not realy, becouse i need to sort this files to display older to newest.

I found one solutions, but they only works like a echo, but he dont display files like a first code, what is on the top.

```
$files = glob( 'pardod/*.html' );
array_multisort(
    array_map( 'filemtime', $files ),
    SORT_NUMERIC,
    SORT_DESC,
    $files
);
print_r( $files);
```

(Sory for my bad english)

Comment: Not clear what you mean?

Comment: i have made a litle page, i add news on it, and when i add new topic, i want they on top, like a lastest news show on top, oldest go down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `print_r($files)` with

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    include $file;
}
```

And you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like this:

```
<?php
$files = array();
$iterator = new DirectoryIterator(dirname(__FILE__));
   foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
   if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
      $files['name'][] = $fileinfo->getFilename();
      $files['edittime'][] = $fileinfo->getMTime();
   }
  }
  array_multisort($files['edittime'],SORT_DESC, $files['name']);
  foreach ($files as $file) {
    include $file;
  };
 ?>
```